# Hard drive loud activity noise after it has finished writing data

Tags: linux, hard-drive, noise, disk-activity

I have an issue with a hard drive making loud activity noises after it has finished writing data.

I am running Linux.

For example, if I copy a file (60GB), then once copying has finished the drive will start making sounds similar to the ones you can hear when system is very heavily swapping. This can last for up to few minutes.

The thing is, it is not swapping at all, I even tried disabling swap completely, so that is ruled out.

`iotop` is not showing any activity.

`echo 1 >/proc/sys/vm/block_dump` is also not showing any activity.

So this appears to be happening outside of OS scope.

If during this time I will try to read or copy another file, then the drive will stop this loud activity, and do what I asked it to do at full speed (no performance drop), once it will be idle, it will resume doing that loud activity again, so this is happening only when the drive itself is idle, with no interruption in read/write performance.

I have checked S.M.A.R.T. and it appears to be fine:

```
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.10.0-12-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MQ01ABD...
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MQ01ABD075
Firmware Version: AX0A4M
User Capacity:    750,156,374,016 bytes [750 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 189) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       1699
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3423
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   077   077   000    Old_age   Always       -       9338
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   168   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3381
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       779
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       308
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       26548
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       32 (Min/Max 6/52)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
220 Disk_Shift              0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
222 Loaded_Hours            0x0032   083   083   000    Old_age   Always       -       7039
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
224 Load_Friction           0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
226 Load-in_Time            0x0026   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       272
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0001   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      9223         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      9221         -
# 3  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      8968         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8965         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8965         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

`dmesg`:

```
[    4.558633] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    4.570269] libata version 3.00 loaded.
[    4.573616] ahci 0000:00:17.0: version 3.0
[    4.573861] ahci 0000:00:17.0: AHCI 0001.0301 32 slots 1 ports 6 Gbps 0x1 impl SATA mode
[    4.573863] ahci 0000:00:17.0: flags: 64bit ncq pm led clo only pio slum part deso sadm sds apst 
[    4.574130] scsi host0: ahci
[    4.574275] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf0136000 port 0xf0136100 irq 123
[    4.890860] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    4.891775] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:e0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[    4.891781] ata1.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:e0 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[    4.925670] ata1.00: ATA-8: TOSHIBA MQ01ABD075, AX0A4M, max UDMA/100
[    4.925677] ata1.00: 1465149168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32), AA
[    4.927217] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:e0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[    4.927225] ata1.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:e0 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[    4.928204] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[    4.929113] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      TOSHIBA MQ01ABD0 4M   PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    4.947364] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 1465149168 512-byte logical blocks: (750 GB/699 GiB)
[    4.947415] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    4.947423] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    4.947473] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    5.098647]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6 sda7 sda8 sda9 sda10
[    5.115598] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

Is this related to some drive functionality which makes it re-arrange the data internally when it is not doing anything, to speed up read access performance, or something like that?

Could this behavior be disabled (or tweaked), like for example using `hdparm` to disable APM?

I tried disabling NCQ, but it did not help, under AHCI flags there is also other stuff:

```
[    4.573863] ahci 0000:00:17.0: flags: 64bit ncq pm led clo only pio slum part deso sadm sds apst
```

It is really driving me nuts, even though it is happening without any performance penalty.

I have other hard drives and they do not behave like that, once a transfer is over (and synced) the drives will remain completely silent.

This is happening only after write operations.

Reading 60GB with:

```
# dd if=/dev/sda8 of=/dev/null bs=10M status=progress
64424509440 bytes (64 GB, 60 GiB) copied, 640 s, 101 MB/s
```

And disk remained quiet.

Writing 60GB with:

```
# dd if=/dev/sda8 of=/dev/sda9 bs=10M status=progress; sync
64424509440 bytes (64 GB, 60 GiB) copied, 1316.57 s, 48.9 MB/s
```

Once `sync` was completed disk started behaving very loudly (thrashing like sounds) for about 2 minutes and 30 seconds.

Swap was off.

Duration depends on the amount of data written, so after writing 10GB it will usually be done within 20 seconds, with 20GB within 50-60 seconds, with 60GB within 150-180 seconds.

Maybe this is related to some post-write additional data integrity checks, but still, there should be a way to tweak this.

Comment: What is the usage percentage of the filesystem on this disk? Potentially it's writing to some internal cache (or "fast access" tracks, or whatever the vendor dreamed up), and is then copying those all over the place once the disk is idle, as the disk has become fragmented. The SMART values all look good.